# Jupiter notebook in VS code: Why does the dropdown not appear?

Tags: visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, dropdown

I set up a **jupyter notebook** in **VS code** (see all versions below):

```
Version: 1.60.1 (Universal)
Commit: 83bd43bc519d15e50c4272c6cf5c1479df196a4d
Date: 2021-09-10T17:09:14.403Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 13.1.8
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0
```

But my **dropdown** does not compile as **expected**.

Here the drop down raw:

```
<details open>
<summary>Want to ruin the surprise?</summary>
<br>
Well, you asked for it!
</details>
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/citrusui/07978f14b11adada364ff901e27c7f61)

It does however not compile as expected.

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You are in Restricted Mode intended for safe code browsing

Remember that VS code has this **security feature** called ['Workspace Trust'](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust)?

There should be a **banner** on top of your window:

[image]

The second sentence tells you **exactly why** the dropdown doesn't work:

> Trust this window to enable **all features**

Click on `Manage` and everything will work again as expected.

[image]